# In der Nähe vom

Tags: german-to-english

> Die Wohnung liegt relativ zentral in der Nähe vom Stadtpark.

I understand the sentence as "the apartment lies in central, near the city park"

What is the use of *vom (von)* here? Do we need to always use it along with "in der Nähe"?

Comment: Note that the capitalization of nouns is mandatory in German.

Comment: Will follow it, thanks.

Comment: "In der Nähe von" translates almost literally to English: "in the vicinity of".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In der Nähe* requires the genitive case.

> In der Nähe des Stadtparks.

However, as with some other genitive constructions, this can be rewritten in terms of von

> In der Nähe vom Stadtpark.

Compare this to

> Das ist das Auto der Frau.

> Das ist das Auto von der Frau.